# $http on success data is the same even if copied (and modified) in another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, copy

I have a tiny problem and I'm not sure it's more an "angular problem" or purely a "javascript problem".
I'm trying to make some sort of "7 errors game" with my resume (learning by doing you know) and I have a problem dissociating the "good version" from the "bad version" (understand the modified one).

Here is the code :

```
var that = this;

function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    var copy = new Object();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }

    return copy;
}

this.resume = null;
this.wrongResume = null;

// get the json
$http.get('resources/resume.json')
.success(function(data) {
    that.resume = clone(data);

    //
    // --> OUT: [...] gagné.
    //
    console.log(that.resume.description[1]);

    that.wrongResume = clone(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataServe.errors.length; i++) {
        that.wrongResume = dataServe.errors[i].action(that.wrongResume);
    };

    //
    // --> OUT: [...] <span ng-click="errors[0].resolution()" class="pointer" ng-hide="errors[0].resolved">mang</span><span ng-show="errors[0].resolved">gagn</span>é.
    // --> should still be: [...] gagné.
    //
    console.log(that.resume.description[1]);
});
```

The `<span ng-click="e[...]">gagn</span>é.` part outs like `mang` is clickable and when clicked on it decreases the score value and displays `gagn` again (which is the original one).

As you can see, I tried to hard copy the object as I just was assigning the value like `that.resume = data;` but didn't have had much more luck.

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: have you tried without the first line in your clone func -  if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a deep copy of your object - copying the properties that are itself arrays or objects isn't enough - you need to copy their properties too and so on (if they have nested objects/arrays)... so this is more a javascript than an angular problem.

So if you use angular you can just use `angular.copy` and things should be working.
https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/docs/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: Works like a charm.
I new it was something like that, thank you. :)